# What are the things to do after recording scenarios in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am currently recording some scenarios for load testing an application using JMeter. I see that there are a ton of HTTP requests recorded (all with the hostname of the app under test). I want to know what are the clean up steps to do after recording these samples?
Ex: Consider that I am recording "Modifying an entry" scenario. In this case, my recorded samples include all the steps I performed:

1. Loading all entries as a list,
2. selecting & loading the required entry on full screen,
3. saving the modified entry to the db and
4. displaying all the entries as list once again.

My questions:

- Should I keep HTTP requests related to all steps (1-4) or just keep the HTTP requests of step 3 as they are the ones directly related to calling the modify API?
- what are the other cleanup steps I should before starting my load testing?

Running all these requests for each of the scenarios under test for 2 concurrent users gives me response times as large as 26 seconds per scenario whereas while performing the same steps in the app UI takes much smaller time than that. So I need some guidance in knowing the best practices to do after recording the samples so that my LT results are accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one best practice: JMeter test needs to replicate the real user using your application via the real browser with 100% accuracy.

If you get higher response times with JMeter it may be caused by:

1. Incorrect recorder configuration when it comes to handling [embedded resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds), you should not be recording these calls but rather configure JMeter to automatically download them using parallel thread pool of 6 users

   [image]

   [image]
2. [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) is missing
3. [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) calls which browser executes in parallel are executed sequentially in JMeter

I cannot suggest on your test design when it comes to business actions implementation as I don't know the expected flows, again you need to inspect what requests are under the hood of real user actions using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and configure JMeter to send exactly the same requests implementing this or that action.

You can avoid copying and pasting repeating parts of the user action flows by introducing [Module Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to replicate my test scenarios as close to a real browser as possible with your inputs above.